# Is 'OpenNTF Domino API' project ready for production usage?

Tags: xpages

A month ago there was an information about 'OpenNTF Domino API' released with some initial binary package available. Is this release stable enough to be used in real applications? I looked to github and last commit is dated on April 4, so there is no development now. Is there anyone using  and having good experience with this API?

Project page:
http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=OpenNTF%20Domino%20API

Comment: Check the different branches... the last commit to master (the release branch) was around the time of the first official release, as would be expected. Nathan, Paul, and Jesse have all committed code to their respective branches in the past week (Nathan as recently as yesterday).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some challenges with using the master branch in XPages. We've done work since April 4th that has made that possible, as well as starting on provisioning the new methods to SSJS. But those features are currently in development branch.

Comment: So current M1 binnary release is not intended for production yet? We use JAVA strictly, no SSJS libraries just simple SSJS code that binds xpages controls to JAVA code.  Is there a description how to create own binnary from github source?

Comment: There's an article I wrote on the wiki in the GitHub project that outlines how to do it https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino/wiki/Plug-and-Play-into-an-NSF-the-org.openntf.domino-way. Nathan's branch is fully up-to-date. You'll need the XPages SDK for Eclipse from OpenNTF, if you don't already, as with any plugin. If it's in godmode we override the session and database global objects accessed from the VariableResolver. Otherwise it uses opensession and opendatabase.

Comment: Hook up with me on Twitter / LinkedIn / Skype (paulswithers) or one of the other project team and we can add you to the Skype chat for the project, if you're looking to use it as an early adopter